# "by" before the gerund, when is needed

Tags: prepositions

Please consider the follow two sentences:

> 1. It is hard to agree that **by** increasing sports facilities is the best
>    way to improve public health.
> 2. The best way to improve public health is **by** increasing the number of
>    sports facilities.

Why the first sentence does not need the preposition "by" while the second one does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sentence 1 what follows "that" is an independent clause that stands on its own:  "Increasing sports facilities is the best way to improve public health." There is no need for "by" in the clause.

In sentence 2 what follows "is" is a prepositional phrase "by increasing the number of sports facilities." Absent "by", there occurs an unintended linkage of "is increasing" as a continuous tense of the verb BE. And this cannot be, so you need the preposition to maintain the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Well, this actually can be; not everybody would note the potential ambiguity in writing, and in speech it wouldn't be ambiguous. But I agree there is a problem there.

Comment: I would contend that even orally sentence 2 hardly functions without "by".

Comment: Flip it around: _Increasing the number of sports facilities is the best way to improve public health._ Where's the _by_?

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence does not need by and the first isn't a sentence with or without by, it's a fragment. There is no subject for the verb, to agree, in the first sentence.

Comment: The subject of the first sentence is "it".